# Set static response from Istio Ingress Gateway

Tags: istio

How do you set a static 200 response in Istio's Ingress Gateway?

We have a situation where we need an endpoint to return a small bit of static content (a bootstrap URL). We could even put it in a header. Can Istio host something like that or do we need to run a pod for no other reason than to return a single word?

Specifically I am looking for a solution that returns 200 via Istio configuration, not a pod that Istio routes to (which is quite a common example and available elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually by creating [VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/) to specific service connected to pod. 
Of course firstly you have to create pod and then attached service to it,
even if your application will return single word.

Istio Gateway’s are responsible for opening ports on relevant
Istio gateway pods and receiving traffic for hosts. That’s it.

The VirtualService: Istio VirtualService’s are what get “attached” to
Gateways and are responsible defining the routes the gateway should implement.
You can have multiple VirtualServices attached to Gateways. But not for the
same domain.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but similar to how a VirtualService can return a 301 redirect, I was hoping that there was a way to just return 200 (maybe with no content).

Comment: Yes, but at the same time you can define denier as Mixer rule  [denier-configuraion](https://medium.com/ww-engineering/istio-ip-whitelists-1633acbd4205). Bu there is nothing prepared for response 200.